# Can't connect Kafka to Zookeeper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

From docker-compose I got this yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:3.1.1
    ports:
      - "2080:2080"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2080
      - ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.1.1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=Topic1:1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=192.168.99.100:2080
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://192.168.99.100:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  schema-registry:
    container_name: schema-registry
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:3.1.1
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=192.168.99.100:2080
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=localhost
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
```

When I stand up this docker the console output ends with:

```
schema-registry | Error while running kafka-ready.
schema-registry | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for Kafka to create /brokers/ids in Zookeeper. timeout (ms) = 40000
schema-registry exited with code 1
```

It seems like kafka never connect Zookeper or something like that, does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure about the ip address provided? You could have used the hostnames to connect.

Comment: Are you trying to use Docker Machine?

Answer (score 0):

Does changing

`SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=192.168.99.100:2080`

into

`SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2080`

help?

Additionally, `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=192.168.99.100:2080` should mention `zookeeper` as well, instead of an IP address. Or, how can you be sure of that IP address?

`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://192.168.99.100:9092` mentions an IP address you might not be able to guarantee as well. For the latter, that IP address could be changed into `kafka`.

I also had challenges in getting Kafka and Zookeeper to work in Docker (via Docker Compose). In the end, https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.0.0-post/examples/kafka-single-node/docker-compose.yml worked for me. You could use that as a source of inspiration.